# build bjsip and use it in visual studio

Tags: c#, c++, pjsip, pjsua2

I want to build pjsip in order to use it (as dll) in my C# project with visual studio. there is a lot of solution on the internet and I have no experience with C++ language so I get confusion between all that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in the most easy way by using a wrapper like [this](https://github.com/siniypin/pjsip4net). It can be installed very simply as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/pjsip4net/0.2.0.28?_src=template).